# Method 'FormulaR1C1' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba, macos, if-statement

I'm having trouble running a macro in Excel (version 15 of 365 on Mac). It fails on this portion:

```
Dim LastRow2 As Long
LastRow2 = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

Range("AV2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR(AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-40]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-39]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-38]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-34]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-33]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-32]<1),AND(RC[" & _
    "ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-31]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-30]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-29]<1),AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-28]<1)),""Error"",""Good"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AV2:AV" & LastRow2)
```

I can't figure out why...I don't see anything wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there is a charter limit for range.formula :/

Comment: Also the linebreak `,AND(RC[" & _ "ZZ"",RC[-` seems wrong to me... the formula will be `...RC[ZZ",...`

Comment: @YowE3K character limit on `.FormulaArray` not `.FormulaR1C1` that I know of.

Comment: @ScottCraner LOL - I decided that I really should check that possibility and was just about to post a comment saying "forget everything I said", and then your comment turned up :D

Comment: As @DirkReichel, I bet the lines should end `...(RC[-41]" & _` the next start `"<>""ZZ""...`

Comment: One more note, once you get the typo fixed you do not need to use `.select` or the autofill.  Just assign directly to the whole range: `Range("AV2:AV" & LastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = _`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion "Range("AV2:AV" & LastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = _" it works very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down your formula leads to great reduction!

Original break down:

```
"=IF(
OR(
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-40]<1), 
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-39]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-38]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-34]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-33]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-32]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-31]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-30]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-29]<1),
    AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"",RC[-28]<1)
),
""Error"",""Good"")"
```

Can be realized to:

```
"=IF(
    AND(
        RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",
        RC[-27]=""I"",
        RC[-26]=""n"",
        OR(
            RC[-40]<1,
            RC[-39]<1,
            RC[-38]<1,
            RC[-34]<1,
            RC[-33]<1,
            RC[-32]<1,
            RC[-31]<1,
            RC[-30]<1,
            RC[-29]<1,
            RC[-28]<1
        )
    ),""Error"",""Good"")"
```

Set this as a `Private Const` at top of module for easy maintenance.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const AV_ErrOrGood As String = "=IF(AND(RC[-41]<>""ZZ"",RC[-27]=""I"",RC[-26]=""n"", OR(RC[-40]<1,RC[-39]<1,RC[-38]<1,RC[-34]<1,RC[-33]<1,RC[-32]<1,RC[-31]<1,RC[-30]<1,RC[-29]<1,RC[-28]<1)),""Error"",""Good"")"

Sub SO45177305()
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    LastRow2 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("AV2:AV" & LastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = AV_ErrOrGood
End Sub
```

Comment: nicely done. it can be shortened even more by using the resulting A1 style formula. I think it's in R1C1 style only because Record Macro converted it